# Can't remove/change onclientclick event from asp button JQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, bind, unbind, onclientclick

I have some code in my site that checks against a credential object. Depending on the type of user, I register a .js file that contains some code that disables functionality. I just want to remove or change the onClick event of an asp button via JQuery but nothing I've tried works.

Here's the .aspx page declaration;

```
<asp:Button  runat="server" ID="SubmitButton"  OnClientClick="return submitbutton_click()" Text="Upload"  onmouseover="this.className='btnReportHover';" onmouseout="this.className='btnReport'"  CssClass="btnReport"/>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<input name="SubmitButton" class="btnReport" id="SubmitButton" onmouseover="this.className='btnReportHover';" onmouseout="this.className='btnReport'" onclick="return submitbutton_click();" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
```

Attempted JQuery that doesn't work;

```
$("#SubmitButton").unbind("onclick");
$("#SubmitButton").attr("onclick",'return ProspectDisabled();');
```

I've also tried by class 'btnReport' as well as using the .off() declaration, unbinding the click event or onClientClick, used .live('click','') etc. Just can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: `$("#SubmitButton").on('click', function() {return ProspectDisabled(); })` would work

Comment: also As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements

Comment: @Pilot i've tried using that exact method, but it doesn't seem to work.  I've also tried to unbind using all of these calls and the onclick event never unbinds;

$('input[id$="SubmitButton"]').unbind("onclick");
$('input[id$="SubmitButton"]').unbind("click");
$("#SubmitButton").unbind("onclick");
$("#SubmitButton").unbind("click");
$(".btnReport").unbind("onclick");
$(".btnReport").unbind("click");
none work

Answer (score 0):

use `.off()`

```
$( "body" )
.off( "click", "#<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>");
```

You should use `<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>` for refering the id of asp button.Because it will change the Id while rendering.

Comment: that doesn't work either, it doesn't change the onclick event of the button, and as i mentioned above i'm unable to get any events to change for that button, but thank you for the suggestion